# how to set the currency on the Opportunity object based on Lead country code

Tags: apex, trigger

i have requirement when i convert  the lead into opportunity.I have country code custom field on the lead.if countrycode is '86' or '+86' then the currency which is standard field on opportunity object set to 'CNY' otherwise set 'Usd'. I am new SFDC. Anyone have sample code.

```
for(Lead l:[select id, convertedOpportunityId from Lead where id in:setConvertedLeadIds AND convertedOportunityid!=null])
{
    if(l.Country_Code__c=='86'|| l.Country_Code__c=='+86') {
        Opportunity opp= new Opportunity();
        opp.id=l.convertedOportunityid;
        opp.CurrencyIsoCode='CNY';
        opplist.add(opp);
    }
}
```

I am getting error:

> Invalid field convertedOportunityid for SObject Lead at line

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any additional content. That's not what comments are for.

Comment: You cannot expect a code to run expectedly after making a typo in field name: convertedOportunityid, apex is code case not any typo insensitive ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your error message *carefully*, you will notice that there is a typo in field API name. Change `convertedOportunityId` to `convertedOpportunityId`.

Error denotes that clearly, I understand that when you are too much involved in code its hard to understand the problem. The way I debug is copy paste the field API name and look for it in Object. Its also a faster way of resolving the issue.